# What assigning my navigation bar an equal top and bottom margin?

Tags: html, css, middleman

I have a navigation bar made from an unordered list:

```
<div id="header">
  <ul id="nav"> 
    <li><%= link_to "home", "#" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "work", "#" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "team", "#" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "contact", "#" %></li>
  </ul> 

  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

With only the following css:

```
#nav{
    margin: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}
```

The browser is giving it a top and bottom margin of 16px, when I haven't told it to:
[image]

I am using a rails-style framework, "middleman", but I doubt that is causing. Does anyone know where it is coming from?

Comment: Are you sure it's #nav that's causing this margin ? If yes check for the source file of where margin is set

Comment: You're missing some piece of CSS code. Try removing certain pieces of CSS till you find the offender. With the amount of info you gave us there's no way we can give you an actual answer. Also. !important works wonders. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<ul></ul>` element gives you this `top` and `bottom` `margin` :

```
ul.nav{
    margin: 0 auto; /*reduce top and bottom margin to 0 and set left-right to auto*/
}
```